# How to generate `getter/setter` for ZF2 and Doctrine using a command line tool?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

How can I generate getter/setter for ZF2 and Doctrine using a command line tool? Like $myEntity->getUsername() and $myEntity->setUsername('foo');
I'm using this to generate entities:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --force --from-database annotation ./Entity/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this script http://mostafa.info/~NKIBl0 
Its really helpful for me. Use it like this:

```
php generateGettersAndSetters.php file.php > generatedFile.php
```

Comment: Thanks Mostafa! It worked flawlessly. (Note to myfelf: some day I will regret executing command line instructions I see on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to utilize a 3rd party script since you're using `DoctrineORMModule`. Doctrine's native `ConvertMapping` command already provides required options to us.

All you need is passing `true` as `generate-methods` parameter value to CLI like below:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project
$ php public/index.php orm:convert-mapping --from-database annotation ./Entity/ --update-entities="true" --generate-methods="true"
```